# Solid black box in the proof environment

Tags: symbols, theorems

I am using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
A = B
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

and an empty square box will be added automatically at the end of the proof. I am wondering how to add a solid black box instead, in an automatic way.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your document class and the relevant (theorem-related) packages.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}` put in the preamble, would it work?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The documentation of [amsthm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) says:

> A QED symbol, □, is automatically appended at the end of a proof environment. To substitute a different end-of-proof symbol, use `\renewcommand` to redefine the command `\qedsymbol`.

Thus, one might proceed as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
```

A mwe to play with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[Proof of the Main Theorem]
  \begin{equation*}
    G(t)=L\gamma!\,t^{-\gamma}+t^{-\delta}\eta(t) \qedhere
  \end{equation*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

If you're looking for [beamer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer), it is quite the same: you have to re-define the template `qed symbol` (almost similar to my previous answer in  [How to customise (e.g. make thicker) the end-proof symbol in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68584/how-to-change-the-end-proof-symbol-in-beamer/68588#68588)).

A mwe:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{qed symbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\begin{proof}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Notice that in this case the symbol will assume the colors of the Beamer color theme currently in use.

Comment: Thank you very much for `\qedhere`!

Comment: @bkarpuz: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 21):

If you are using the `amsthm` package (or one of the `ams` documentclasses), then the symbol used is given by the command `\qedsymbol`.  It can be redefined as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  Clear.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Immediately followed, of course, by `\begin{self-doubting student}`!