# Blocks at the End of a Solution Structure

Tags: theorems, amsthm

so a couple of months ago I created my own package. Everything in it works great, and so far it does everything I need it to do, the way I need it to. But I want to change one thing. When I made the package, I found it necessary to create a structure declaration in the package that says

```
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
```

Until now, I have been very happy with it. But I've decided (in order to separate the solutions from the surrounding text) that I want the structure to add a black square at the end every time the structure ends. Could somebody tell me how to modify my code to do this?

Comment: I'm using amsmath.

Comment: See [Solid black box in the proof environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98382/5764).

Comment: That's fine for the proof environment, but how do I force my created environment to do a similar practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}`, add the following lines:

```
\RequirePackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  qed=$\blacksquare$,
  numbered=no,
  bodyfont=\itshape
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{solution}
```

Since `\blacksquare` requires `amssymb`, you will also need this package (if you are not already loading it):

```
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
```

An example with a document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  qed=$\blacksquare$,
  numbered=no,
  bodyfont=\itshape
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{solution}

\begin{document}

\begin{solution}
\lipsum*[4]
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the {mystyle} part do?

Comment: `mystyle` is the name of the defined style. You can use any other name you like more.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `solution` be similar to `proof` of [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) by using the following construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\solutionname}{\textbf{Solution}}
\newenvironment{solution}[1][\solutionname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{solution}
  \begin{equation*}
    G(t)=L\gamma!\,t^{-\gamma}+t^{-\delta}\eta(t) \qedhere
  \end{equation*}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

The above definition for `solution` is taken directly from [`amsclass.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/amsclass.dtx) where `proof` is defined. The only thing I've changed is the title.