# Is there a way to draw the little black square at the end of proof without using the environment \begin{proof}?

Tags: amsmath, amsthm

Is there a way to draw the little black square at the end of proof without using the environment `\begin{proof}... \end{proof}`?

I know that one way is like says in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98382/solid-black-box-in-the-proof-environment) but I'd like to know if is it possible to place that little black square at determined position, say (7,-8) in coordinate scale for example?

If yes, how do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QED symbol could be placed at a desired position, e.g.--

[image]

with a tikz node whose position is specified w.r.t. the `page.center` (where coordinates such as `(6,9)` have to be calibrated as needed):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{showframe}     % for this example
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\QED}[1]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node 
                         at ($(current page.center) + (#1)$) 
                                         {\rule{7pt}{7pt}};}

\begin{document}
 \textit{Proof.} Proof of simple theorems are 
                            quite easily done. \QED{6,9}

 \QED{0,0} \QED{-6,6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Evidently this solution is built on the framework of Sigur and the suggestion by marmot :).

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

(you can use any other symbol as QED symbol; to push it to right use `\hfill`)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{showframe} % for this example
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for this example
\usepackage{amsthm}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{7pt}{7pt}}
\begin{document}
\noindent\textit{Proof.} \lipsum[1]\hfill\qedsymbol
\end{document}
```

Comment: should get the fastest correct answer badge ! ...just noting a slight difference in my compiled pdf-- where the black square comes on the _next line._

Comment: @ParthaD. That is an artifact of `lipsum`, which auto-adds the `\par` at the end of the paragraph.  Load the package with the `[nopar]` option.

Comment: You should have used `\noindent\textit{Proof.} There is no such way.\hfill\qedsymbol`. (+1 some time ago;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help Sigur, this is helpful. Though this solution is 'fixed'. The little black square is always at a determined static position. Could it be possible to place it at determined coordinate position?

Comment: @marmot there's no such way.. lol

Comment: @user178403, so you don't want the square at end of last line of the proof? I think that to put it in some coordinate on the page you have to use `picture`, I'm not sure about that. Also, in that case, you'll have to test the coordinates to find the good ones.

Comment: yes, I want the square at the end of last line of the proof but with specific coordinates. Seems like Partha D.'s answer does it.